# matrices and eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

can you explain the question to me? thanks

Question : Give a 2 x 2 matrix matrix A such that A has no real eigenvalues $A^2$ has an eigenvalue of -1 with algebric and geometric multiplicity of 2

**i dont know where to start**

thanks

Comment: is the eigenvalue of A (your example ) not equal to 0?

Answer (score 3):

Try

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: the eigen value of A will be 0 and 0 is a real number

Comment: Are the eigenvalues of $A$ 0? What is the null space of  $A-0I = A$? Or - Consider $A- \lambda I$ and solve for what $\lambda$ makes the null space nontrivial. You shouldn't get 0.

Comment: @matheu96 Check carefully before downvoting: the characteristic polynomial of $\;A\;$ is $\;x^2+1\;$ . Not only this, but zero is an eigenvalue of a matrix iff the matrix is singular, and this one is not singular.

Comment: can you please explain how you got the matrix? thanks

Comment: @matheu96 Thinking of the easiest example of non-real complex number ($i$) which squared ($-1$) is already real. Figuring out a $\;2\times2\;$ matrix whose char. polynomial is $\;x^2+1\;$ was pretty easy.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^2$ has eigenvalue $-1$ with geometric multiplicity $2$, then we must have $A^2 = -I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix).

That is, $A^2$ yields the rotation by $180^\circ$.  Can you think of a linear transformation that, when applied twice, results in a rotation by $180^\circ$?

Comment: i got this transformation:

Comment: What transformation?

Comment: i got A = \begin{bmatrix}cosx&-sinx\\sinx&cosx\end{bmatrix}  is that correct?

Comment: But for what value of $x$? Not every $x$ will work here.

Comment: for x = 90 degree is that correct?

Comment: That's right. And what matrix does that give you? The other answer uses $-90$.