# An example of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ without real eigenvalues and s.t $A^2$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue with algebraic and geometric multiplicity $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Basically I tried the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}  0 &  -1\\
1  &  0\\
\end{bmatrix}

but this eigenvalue of $A^2$ is $1$,and $-1$ which has algebraic multiplicity is $1$. I can not find any $2 \times 2$ matrix that satisfies both has $-1$ as an eigenvalue and algebraic multiplicity $2$.

Comment: Take $\mathrm i\cdot I_2\in \mathcal M_2(\mathbf C]$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @anzu Your matrix squares to $-I$. It seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that the matrix squares to the negative identity matrix works? I don't quiet get it. @EuYu

Comment: Do you want a matrix with only real entries or?

Comment: @anzu $-I$ is a matrix with eigenvalue $-1$ with algebraic and geometric multiplicity $2$.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1858574/81360)

Comment: @snulty well the question does not specify it, so I assume non real entries are also acceptable.

Comment: @EuYu Sorry for asking it, but what is −I exactly?

Comment: @anzu It's the negative identity matrix.

Comment: @EuYu But it does not satisfy the condition that the algebraic multiplicity 2 though. The solution for $A^2$ will be $(\lambda -1)(\lambda + 1)$ which have algebraic multiplicity 1.

Comment: @EuYu Furthermore the matrix $A$ itself also has a real solution. Where $$
        \begin{matrix}
        -1 & 0 \\
         0 & -1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$give us that $(\lambda + 1)^2$ , so the solution of $A$ is $\lambda = -1$ The first requirement says the matrix $A$ should not have a real number solution.

Comment: @anzu I don't understand what you mean. You want a matrix $A$ without real eigenvalues such that $A^2$ has eigenvalue $-1$ with geometric and algebraic multiplicity $2$. Your matrix has eigenvalues $\pm i$. These are not real. It has square $A^2 = -I$, and $-I$ is a matrix (the only $2\times 2$ matrix) with eigenvalue $-1$ with algebraic and geometric multiplicity $2$. It entirely fits the required criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Well basically the matrix $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        -1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ works. The eigenvalue of this matrix is $\lambda^2 + 1$ and the eigenvalue of this matrix $A^2$ is $(\lambda +1)(\lambda + 1)$ where both algebraic and geometric multiplicity 2